# How to move array values and keys to front of array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of values:

```
Array ( [0] => hello [5] => Im [50] => from [1032] => Europe [1039] => where [1117] => are [1137] => you [1873] => from? )
```

What is the best way to unset these values and move everything to front ?

To be like this:

```
 Array ( [0] => hello [1] => Im [2] => from [3] => Europe [4] => where [5] => are [6] => you [7] => from? )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `array_values`.

```
$myarray = array_values($myarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

try with `foreach`

```
foreach($arr as $v) {
  $newarr[] = $v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
$arr = array();
foreach($arr as $value) {
   $arr[] = $v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set an arbitrary array then use a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($currentArray as $curr) {
    $arbitraryArray[] = $curr;
}
```

then set it back to $currentArray;